# Why are my input radio elements greyed out?

Tags: html, radio-button, radioelement

I've got three radio input elements:

```
<input type="radio" id="visitor" />Visitor
<input type="radio" id="ucstudent" />UC Student
<input type="radio" id="ucemployee" />UC Employee
```

They are all greyed out (the radio button itself as well as the text). Why? Nothing else on my form is (greyed out).

My .css file does nothing with type="radio", id="visitor", id="ucstudent", or id="ucemployee".

Comment: You have to add a name property to your radios. If they all belong to the same radio group they need to have the same name.

Comment: Doens't work; I added to them all: "name="travelertype" and they stay greyer than the coast of Ireland.

Comment: I have this issue with the materializecss library.

Answer (score 1):

Add the name attribute to the inputs:

```
<input type="radio" id="visitor" name="type" />Visitor
<input type="radio" id="ucstudent" name="type" />UC Student
<input type="radio" id="ucemployee" name="type" />UC Employee
```

Comment: Nope - makes no diff. I don't know why it would - it doesn't seem to make much sense.